# Pygame only advances on keypress

Tags: python, pygame

I imagine this is a simple fix and have seen similar questions, but this is really frustrating me. Basically when you run the game, it only advances the simulation on a keypress, and not at a set framerate.

https://pastebin.com/aP6LsMMA

The main code is:

```
pg.init()
clock = pg.time.Clock()
FPS = 10
# ...
Game = Control()
while not Game.done:
    Game.main_loop()
    pg.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)
pg.quit()
```

and the event handler method - within the Control class - is:

```
def event_handler(self):
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                self.done = True
            elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                self.scene.process_event(event)
```

The weird thing to me is that, at the bottom of the pastebin, is my old testing code that is not done with classes for Scenes/Control. However, to my eye it should work exactly the same. I've tried putting in the clock both in and out of the Control class to no avail.

Any help (and general tips!) greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: you should run `process_event()` for all events, and inside `process_event` check `KEYDOWN`. OR even you should  only change direction inside `process_event()` and rest (update,draw,checkc collision) should be executed outside `process_event()` - after event loop - even outside `event_handler` - in separated function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`process_event()` should only change variables which depend on events but it shouldn't update other values which should be updated in every frame. You have to move some elements to new method `update()` and execute it in every loop.

More or less

```
class Scene:

    def process_event(self, event):
        pass

    def update(self):
        pass

class GamePlayState(Scene):

    def process_event(self, event):
        self.snake.get_key(event)

    def update(self):
        self.snake.update()
        self.snake.food_check(self.apple)
        self.snake.collision_check()
        if self.snake.alive == False:
            print("GAME OVER")
            print(self.snake.points)
            self.done = True

class Control:

    def update(self):
        self.scene.update()

    def main_loop(self):
        self.event_handler()
        self.update()
        self.scene_checker()
        self.draw()
```

---

Full working code

```
import pygame as pg
import sys
import random
import queue

# TODO: Walls, queue for keypress, scene stuff, 2 player, difficulty(?)

""" ######################
         PREAMBLE
    ###################### """

""" Dictionaries for direction/velocity mapping - stolen from https://github.com/Mekire """
DIRECT_DICT = {"left" : (-1, 0), "right" : (1, 0),
               "up" : (0,-1), "down" : (0, 1)}

KEY_MAPPING = {pg.K_LEFT : "left", pg.K_RIGHT : "right",
               pg.K_UP : "up", pg.K_DOWN : "down"}

OPPOSITES = {"left" : "right", "right" : "left",
             "up" : "down", "down" : "up"}

""" Colour Mapping """
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
DARK_GREY = (70, 70, 70)
GREY = (211, 211, 211)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
COLOUR_MAP = {"snake": GREEN, "apple": RED, "wall": BLACK, "surface": GREY, "background": DARK_GREY }

""" ################
        CLASSES
    ################ """

""" ####################### Object Classes ########################## """

class Square:
    """ All other objects in the game will be built up from this """
    def __init__(self, pos, colour, length):
        self.xi, self.yi = pos # i for index, p for pixel
        self.colour = colour
        self.length = length

    def display(self):
        xp, yp = self.sq_to_pixs(self.xi, self.yi) # (x = left side, y = top edge)
        pg.draw.rect(screen, self.colour, (xp, yp, self.length, self.length), 0)

    def sq_to_pixs(self, x, y):
    # Converts index of square to pixel coords
        px = (x+1)*(2*MARGIN + SQUARE_SIZE) - MARGIN - SQUARE_SIZE
        py = (y+1)*(2*MARGIN + SQUARE_SIZE) - MARGIN
        return (px, py)

    def index_coords(self): # TODO - remove for direct ref?
        return (self.xi, self.yi)

class Arena:
    """ A grid within which the game takes place """
    def __init__(self, size, square_length, colour):
        self.size = size # i.e. number of squares = size**2 for square arena
        self.length = square_length # i.e. per square dimension
        self.colour = colour
        self.squares = [ [] for i in range(self.size) ]
        for y in range(self.size):
            for x in range(self.size):
                self.squares[y].append(Square((x,y), self.colour, self.length))

    def display(self):
        for y in self.squares:
            for square in y:
                square.display()

class Snake:
    """ Class for the agent(s) """
    def __init__(self, pos, colour, square_length):
        self.xi, self.yi = pos
        self.colour = colour
        self.size = 3
        self.length = square_length
        self.direction = "right"
        self.direction_queue = queue.Queue(4) # TODO
        self.points = 0
        self.growing = False
        self.alive = True
        self.squares = []
        for x in range(self.size): # horizontal initial orientation
            self.squares.append(Square((self.xi - x, self.yi), self.colour, self.length))

    def display(self):
        for square in self.squares:
            square.display()

    def food_check(self, apple):
        if self.squares[0].index_coords() == apple.square.index_coords():
            self.growing = True
            self.points += apple.points_value
            apple.respawn([self])

    def collision_check(self, walls = None):
        xh, yh = self.squares[0].index_coords()
        body = self.squares[-1:0:-1] # going backwards thru array as forwards [0:-1:1] didnt work...

        def _collide(obstacles):
            for sq in obstacles:
                _x, _y = sq.index_coords()
                if (_x == xh) and (_y == yh):
                    self.alive = False

        _collide(body)
        if walls is not None:
            _collide(walls)

    def update(self):
         # Add new head based on velocity and old head
        velocity = DIRECT_DICT[self.direction]
        head_coords = [ (self.squares[0].index_coords()[i] + velocity[i]) for i in (0,1) ]
        # Wrap around screen if reach the end
        for i in (0, 1):
            if head_coords[i] < 0:
                head_coords[i] = SQUARES_PER_ARENA_SIDE - 1
            elif head_coords[i] > SQUARES_PER_ARENA_SIDE - 1:
                head_coords[i] = 0

        self.squares.insert(0, Square(head_coords, self.colour, self.length))
        if self.growing:
            self.growing = False
        else:
            del self.squares[-1]

    """
    def queue_key_press(self, key):
        for keys in KEY_MAPPING:
            if key in keys:
                try:
                    self.direction_queue.put(KEY_MAPPING[keys], block=False)
                    break
                except queue.Full:
                    pass
    """

class Player(Snake):
    """ Human controlled snake via arrow keys """
    def __init__(self, pos, colour, size):
        Snake.__init__(self, pos, colour, size)

    def get_key(self, event):
        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN and event.key in KEY_MAPPING:
                new_direction = KEY_MAPPING[event.key]
                if new_direction != OPPOSITES[self.direction]:
                    self.direction = new_direction

class Apple:
    """ Food our (veggie) snake is greedily after """
    def __init__(self, colour, length, points_value, snake):
        self.colour = colour
        self.length = length
        self.xi, self.yi = self._rand_coords()
        self.points_value = points_value
        self.square = Square((self.xi, self.yi), self.colour, self.length)

    def _rand_coords(self):
        rand_num = lambda x: random.randint(0, x)
        _x = rand_num(SQUARES_PER_ARENA_SIDE-1)
        _y = rand_num(SQUARES_PER_ARENA_SIDE-1)
        return _x, _y

    def respawn(self, obstacles):
        _x, _y = self._rand_coords()
        for ob in obstacles:
            for sq in ob.squares:
                while sq.index_coords() == (_x, _y):
                    _x, _y = self._rand_coords()
        self.square.xi, self.square.yi = _x, _y

    def display(self):
        self.square.display()


""" ################ SCENES ####################### """    

class Scene:
    """ Overload most of this - barebones structure
    A bit pointless in current state but easily expanded """
    def __init__(self):
        self.done = False

    def when_activated(self):
        pass

    def reset(self):
        self.done = False

    def render(self):
        pass

    def process_event(self, event):
        pass

    def update(self):
        pass

class StartUp(Scene):
    def __init__(self):
        Scene.__init__(self)

    def render(self):
        # test placeholder
        pass

    def when_activated(self):
        print("Press any key to continue")

    def process_event(self, event):
        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            self.done = True

class GamePlayState(Scene):
    def __init__(self):
        Scene.__init__(self)
        self.arena = Arena(SQUARES_PER_ARENA_SIDE, SQUARE_SIZE, COLOUR_MAP["surface"])
        self.snake = Player(SNAKE_START, COLOUR_MAP["snake"], SQUARE_SIZE)
        self.apple = Apple(COLOUR_MAP["apple"], SQUARE_SIZE, 1, self.snake)
        self.font = pg.font.SysFont("courier new", 50)

    def render(self):
        screen.fill(COLOUR_MAP["background"])
        self.arena.display()
        self.apple.display()
        self.snake.display()
        text = self.font.render(str(self.snake.points), True, [255,255,255])
        screen.blit(text, (500, 400))

    def process_event(self, event):
        self.snake.get_key(event)

    def update(self):
        self.snake.update()
        self.snake.food_check(self.apple)
        self.snake.collision_check()
        if self.snake.alive == False:
            print("GAME OVER")
            print(self.snake.points)
            self.done = True



""" ################## CONTROL CLASS  #########################"""

class Control:
    def __init__(self):
        #self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        #self.fps = FPS
        self.done = False
        self.scene_array = [StartUp(), GamePlayState()]
        self.scene_index = 0 # dirty way whilst dict method needs tinkering
        #self.scene_dict = {"START": StartUp(), "GAME": GamePlayState()} #TODO
        self.scene = self.scene_array[self.scene_index]
        #self.scene = self.scene_dict["START"]
        self.scene.when_activated()

    def event_handler(self):
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                self.done = True
            elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                self.scene.process_event(event)

    def scene_checker(self):
        if self.scene.done:
            self.scene.reset() # for reuse  - TODO
            self.scene_index = (self.scene_index + 1) % len(self.scene_array)
            self.scene = self.scene_array[self.scene_index]
            self.scene.when_activated()
            #self.scene = self.scene_dict[self.scene.next]

    def update(self):
        self.scene.update()

    def draw(self):
        self.scene.render()

    def main_loop(self):
        self.event_handler()
        self.update()
        self.scene_checker()
        self.draw()


""" ################ RUN GAME ################ """

""" Game paramaters """
SQUARE_SIZE = 20 # pixels
SQUARES_PER_ARENA_SIDE = 20 # squares
MARGIN = 2 # pixels
SNAKE_START = (int(SQUARES_PER_ARENA_SIDE/2), int(SQUARES_PER_ARENA_SIDE/2)) # square coords

pg.init()
clock = pg.time.Clock()
#  Square.display() and a few others need a direct reference to "screen" TODO implement better
w, h = 620, 620
SCREEN_SIZE = [w, h]
FPS = 10
screen = pg.display.set_mode(SCREEN_SIZE)

Game = Control()
while not Game.done:
    Game.main_loop()
    pg.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)
pg.quit()
```